# TypeScript dynamic property type on class

Tags: dynamic, typescript, typescript1.8

There is a way to declare the type of dynamic class property if it's accessed by `[]` operator, like on the following example:

```
class Foo {
  [key: string]: number;
}

let a = new Foo();
let b = a['bar']; //Here, the compiler knows that b is a number
```

But is there a way to declare the same thing, without `[]` operator?
A way to write this:

```
let a = new Foo();
let b = a.someProperty;
```

And letting TypeScript knows that `someProperty` is of type `number`, because we say to it: *All unknown properties on `Foo` are of type number*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think its is possible. When you define class you define 'static' information about its properties and methods. If you specify indexer - it means just that - that the objects of the class will have indexer, not any properties. Thats what classes are for after all - to define structure of your business entities.

The only way I am aware of doing something similar to what you want is by using object literals. For example this will work:

```
let x: { PropA: number, [x: string]: number };
x = { PropA: 1, PropX: 2, PropY: 3, PropZ: 4 };
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I totally agree with your point, classes are here to define a structure and I'm not surprised it's not possible, because it doesn't make a lot of sense. By the way, your suggestion about object literals might help, because at some point during my application lifetime, I have information about these dynamic properties, so maybe I could do something hackish with that. Thanks!